# django charField not accepts numbers

Tags: django

I'm new to django and i was testing CURD and it worked correctly till i found something weird

i have charfield which not accepting any numbers and showing an error when i get all records

```
Reverse for 'updateUser' with arguments '('uuu1',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried
```

views.py

```
def signup(request):
    form = UserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #     fullname = request.POST['fullname']
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            form = UserForm(request.POST)
    else:
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'singup.html', context)


def updateUser(request, fullname):
    user = User.objects.get(fullname__icontains=fullname)
    form = UserForm(instance=user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'singup.html', context)


def getAllUsers(request):
    print("getAllUsers")
    thesearchValue = ''
    if 'SearchValue' in request.GET:
        thesearchValue = request.GET['SearchValue']
        print(thesearchValue)
        print(request.GET['SearchValue'])
        allUsers = User.objects.filter(fullname__icontains=thesearchValue)  # all()
        # return render(request,'getUsersInfo.html',{'allUsers':allUsers})
        return render(request, 'getUsersInfo.html', {'allUsers': allUsers})
    else:
        print("Empty")
        allUsers = User.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'getUsersInfo.html', {'allUsers': allUsers})


def deleteUser(request, fullname):
    print('delete the user')
    todelete = User.objects.filter(fullname=fullname)
    todelete.delete()
    return redirect(getAllUsers)
```

Template

```
<form method="GET">
    {% csrf_token %}
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search this blog" name="SearchValue">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Department</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for x in allUsers%}
        <tr>
            <td>{{x.fullname}}</td>
            <td>{{x.email}}</td>
            <td>{{x.Resp}}</td>
            <td>
                <form method="GET" action="{% url 'updateUser' x.fullname %}">
                    <button class="btn btn--radius btn--green" type="submit"><img src="{% static 'img/update.png' %} "></button>
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form method="GET" action="{% url 'deleteUser' x.fullname %}">
                    <button class="btn btn--radius btn--green" type="submit"><img src="{% static   'img/delete (2).png' %} "></button>
                </form>                </td> 
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

Urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('signup.html',views.signup,name=''),
path('getUsersInfo.html',views.getAllUsers,name=''),
url(r'^deleteUser/(?P<fullname>\D+)/$',views.deleteUser, name='deleteUser'),
url(r'^updateUser/(?P<fullname>\D+)/$',views.updateUser, name='updateUser'),
```

]

notice that I'm sending fullname as an arguments in update and delete functions but even this should not be the problem.

also after i save the record including the number it's showing in the database but when i try to get all the records in the front end it's through that error

Comment: Add your urls.py

Comment: do you believe your comment is readable?

Comment: i edit the question just check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your regex expression \D+ means "one or more non-numbers", see https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Regexe.html#zz-2. I would recommend using just

```
'updateUser/<str:fullname>/'
```

Comment: thank you Paul i change it and still facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

i found that the issue in my url

paul suggest to pass the object itself without regex and when i tried that i used url as below

```
    url(r'^updateUser/<str:fullname>/$',views.updateUser, name='updateUser'),
```

and it seems that u only can use path with the objects

```
    path(r'^updateUser/<str:fullname>/$',views.updateUser, name='updateUser'),
```

now it's working fine